# Cannot control legend.position in ggplot2 when using facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following code and graphs using `mtcars` data as example, I try to put the legend at `bottom`. It works fine without using `theme_bw()` in the first graph. Once I add `theme_bw()`, the legend moves to the right. What have I done wrong, and how to fix this? Thanks.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg,
             color = factor(am)
             )
         ) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(vs)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

```r
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg,
             color = factor(am))) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(vs)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use the "theme\_light()" together with "theme" in a ggplot command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803561/is-it-possible-to-use-the-theme-light-together-with-theme-in-a-ggplot-comm)

Comment: @camille Yes. Looking back it is kind of the same  issue but it would be difficult for users to identify the links between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of `theme` and `theme_bw` because `theme_bw` would override the setting in `theme` if `theme_bw` is at the end.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg,
             color = factor(am))) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(mtcars$vs)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. I haven't thought about that but it makes sense now.